# MySql Sever won't start on Mac OSX using MAMP

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I just installed MAMP and I can not get it working. Apache works just fine but mysql does not start and it doesn't generate a log file, it just stays red.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.4 and MAMP 2.0.5. I don't have mysql installed, but as far as I can tell MAMP comes with it.

Comment: Where do you tell MySQL to store its logs, and is that writable by the user you start MySQL with? Also, try to start `mysqld` from the command line, that does that do?

Comment: I'm using MAMP Pro, but hopefully the same will apply. MAMP installs its own version of the LAMP stack. So the logs might not be where you expect. I get to the MAMP MySQL log from the 'Log' menu in the MAMP app.

Comment: The logs of Apache, MySQL and PHP of MAMP / MAMP PRO are stored in this folder: /Applications/MAMP/logs

Comment: Thanks @Wrikken, I started manually mysql and now MAMP is running ok, although it seems like it cannot starts when the application starts